# Packet Tracer 7.2.1 does not support eigrp for ipv6

Tags: ipv6, packet-tracer, eigrp

I'm trying to enable eigrp for ipv6 in packet tracer but is seems to only have ospf and rip for ipv6.

Is this a recent limitation?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No It is support for IPV6 Eigrp, You need to enable eigrp on Interface level.

```
 int gigabitEthernet 0/0/0
 ipv6 address AB80::10:1/64
 ipv6 eigrp 10
```

Comment: I did, try to enable it on the interface level of a svi vlan 100, however after ipv6 there is no eigrp command in packet tracer. There only appears ospf and rip.